# What is wrong with making a constructor dependency optional and initializing it from within the constructor?

Tags: dart, dependency-injection

I'm new to Dart. I'm coming from Ruby and trying to understand dependency injection. It's a bit hard to get my head around all the examples I've seen online. There seems to be this idea of DI containers -- which seem foreign and overly complex to me.

So naturally, I keep drifting toward patterns and analogies that fit my Ruby mental model better.

I've come up with this example, and while it's probably not idiomatic Dart, I'm wondering the following:

1. What's wrong with this approach if anything?
2. What makes DI containers any better/worse than this?

```
void main() {
  // Young Man
  Man youngMan = Man();
  youngMan.age(); // I am 12

  // Older Man
  Man olderMan = Man(base: OlderPerson());
  olderMan.age(); // I am 39
}

abstract class Person {
  void age();
}

class YoungPerson implements Person {
  void age() {
    print('I am 12');
  }
}

class OlderPerson implements Person {
  void age() {
    print('I am 39');
  }
}

class Man {
  Person base;

  Man({Person base = null}) : this.base = base ?? YoungPerson();

  void age() {
    print('Hello from Man!!!') // This is some work that happens only in Man
    base.age();
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give maybe a quick example/explanation of dependency injection? I'm unfamiliar with its purpose.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Like inheritance and mixins, dependency injection (DI) is a way to share code. Unlike inheritance and mixins, it does not couple your class to other classes. Instead, you pass in "collaborators" that perform work as needed. In the example I've posted, you have a default collaborator of `YoungPerson`, but this default can be swapped out as needed (ex: `OlderPerson`).

This makes testing much easier as you can send in mocks for collaborators rather than trying to stub behavior on super classes or mixins.

Comment: Lets say your take out the `Man` class and just do `Person youngMan = YoungPerson();` and `Person olderMan = OlderPerson();` instead. Would this take away the functionality you currently have?

Comment: My example is obviously contrived. Imagine that the collaborators are service classes that perform some work in addition to the class that they are passed into. I'll update the `age` method in the `Man` class so you can see what I mean.

Comment: What's wrong is that you're hardcoding the initialization of the dependencies. If those never change, and this code doesn't need to be tested, then it's OK.

Comment: I'm optionally providing a default for convenience. It can be omitted of course. And as per my example, it can be overwritten at will. So no hard coding that I see. But how is the container DI pattern different/better? And what in my example would make the code untestable? Quite the contrary from what I can tell. Maybe provide an actual answer for evaluation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are wondering whether it is okay to make the component's dependency optional and in case it hasn't been provided, initialize the component with a default instance. In other words, the `Man` component has a `Person` dependency. In case no person is supplied to `Man` a new instance of `YoungPerson` is used.

Whether it is okay for `Man` to initialize a `YoungPerson` depends on whether `YoungPerson` is a Local Default of a Foreign Default. [DIPP&P](https://mng.bz/BYNl) states the following about Local and Foreign Defaults:

> *A Local Default is a default implementation of a Dependency that originates in the same module or layer.*
>
> *When you’re developing a class that has a Dependency, you probably have a particular implementation of that Dependency in mind. If you’re writing a domain service that accesses a Repository, you’re most likely planning to develop an implementation of a Repository that uses a relational database.*
>
> *It would be tempting to make that implementation the default used by the class under development. But when such a prospective default is implemented in a different assembly, using it as a default means creating a hard reference to that other assembly, effectively violating many of the benefits of loose coupling described in chapter 1. Such implementation is the opposite of a Local Default — it’s a Foreign Default. A class that has a hard reference to a Foreign Default is applying the Control Freak anti-pattern. We’ll discuss Control Freak in chapter 5.*
>
> (source: DIPP&P, section 4.2.2)

Although Local Defaults are not a bad thing per se, I typically advise against their use because it decentralizes the creation of dependencies from the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/) (in your example, `main` is your Composition Root), and makes it possible to *forget* to supply the dependency, which will then cause for a possible incorrect default to be used. Instead, it's much clearer and safer to have all a class's dependencies to be required.

The use of Local Defaults, however, is a discussion separate from whether or not you should use a DI Container. DI, as a practice, helps in making your application code more loosely coupled and, therefore, more flexible and maintainable. DI Containers on the other hand, *can* help in making your Composition Root more maintainable. I say, *can* because in some cases it makes more sense in building object graphs by hand (by using the `new` keyword in your `main` method) as you are currently doing. DI Containers are especially useful when use [Convention over Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) and register all dependencies in the DI Container in an automated fashion (a.k.a. Auto-Registration).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Seems it diverged a bit from my central concern -- probably because I didn't explain myself well. Coming from a dynamic language, I'm not used to DI containers and special libraries to handle this, and thus these ideas seem overly complex and boilerplate heavy to me. Regarding the citation, do the theories that DIPP&P propose stand in practice? I've yet to see code that doesn't require the occasional wrapper class or minor refactor. I've seen clean boundaries, good separation, and clean code in general, but never to the degree implied by that citation. Have you?

Comment: Even in the .NET community, there is still a debate about when to use DI Containers, and even DIPP&P has an [elaborate section](https://livebook.manning.com/book/dependency-injection-principles-practices-patterns/chapter-12/section-12-3) on that. The book is written by Mark Seemann and myself and, as experts in the field, both Mark and I even diverge on this topic, which can be read [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/) and [here](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/). Obviously, as a creator of a DI Container myself, I'm biased towards using one.

Comment: But about the citation, the difference between Local Defaults and Foreign Defaults is certainly more than just theory. But if your application is small, you might not have many different modules in the system (this might mean that every dependency is *Local*) and dependency management of *modules* might, therefore, not be a big issue. So there is (as always) the context to consider.

Comment: BTW, I've been using "poor man's DI" or pure DI for years in Ruby with local and foreign defaults and have never run into any issues. In fact, I've never thought of them in those terms, and appreciate your distinction. I have however been aware of domain boundaries and directional dependency, so perhaps that helped mitigate the issues with foreign defaults? Looking over Mark's article, I do think the debate around containers is enriched by defaults. Injecting deps at each point of instantiation would be a nightmare for me.